# How to add double quotes across a decoded string in python?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, utf-8

There is a byte format string which gets decoded as follows:

```
     byte_string = b'sampletext\r\n'
     decoded_string = byte_string.decode("utf-8")

     output is: sampletext
```

Now there should be double quotes across output and for that purpose i did as follows:

```
     print( "\""+sampletext+"\"" )
     output is: "sampletext
                "
     expected output should be: "sampletext"
```

I have tried various ways of doing that but not able to succeed this problem. Hence please help, badly stuck.

Comment: Your decoded string ends in a CRLF. Do you want to strip it? Then call `.strip()` on the decoded string.

Comment: @L3viathan i don't want to strip. Only the decode string should have double quotes across it.

Comment: But your output *does* have double quotes around it. I see one before the `s` and one after the newline.

Comment: @L3viathan well your information decoded string ends in a CRLF was useful. problem is solved i did as: ' " ' +''.join(sampletext.splitlines())+' " ' now output is "sampletext". Thanks